# Automatically switch to screen built-in speakers when available

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have a two screen setup, each screen with their built-in speakers. All works well except for sound setting automatically switching to digital output every time the screens goes off after which I have to set them back in the setting.

I could go around this and switch off any power-saving/security locks, but I'd really prefer not to with three kids at home. I already have `switch-on-port-available` and `switch-on-connect` modules enabled and loaded. Is there any way to configure those modules to treat my screen speakers same as USB speakers?